# Flipping 6 heads in a row with double headed pennies

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Rosencrantz chooses a coin from Guildenstern's collection of one hundred pennies and promptly tosses six heads in a row. While rhapsodizing over his good luck, he learns that four of the pennies were two-headed. The probability that Rosencrantz chose one of the two-headed pennies given that he flipped six heads in a row can be expressed in the form $m/n$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m + n$.

There is a $\cfrac{1}{25}$ chance that Rosencratz gets the two-headed penny, and if he does, the probability of getting 6 heads in a row is $1 \cdot \cfrac{1}{25} = \cfrac{1}{25}$.

There is a $\cfrac{96}{100}$ chance that Rosencratz gets the normal penny. The probability of getting $6$ heads in a row is $\cfrac{96}{100} \cdot \left(\cfrac{1}{2}\right)^6 = \cfrac{3}{200}$.

Adding $\cfrac{1}{25}$ and $\cfrac{3}{200}$ is $\cfrac{11}{200}$.

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct or not.

Comment: What you have done gives you the probability of $\frac{8}{200}+\frac{3}{200}= \frac{11}{200}$ of getting six heads in a row.  You need to find the conditional probability of having a double headed coin given that you got six heads in a row.

Comment: Good so far.  You've worked out the probability that $R$ gets $6$ Heads in a row.  Now, what portion of that is explained by his having drawn a two headed coin?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the conditional probability

Comment: Do you have a _definition_ of "conditional probability" you can look up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly calculated the probability of $6$ heads in a row. Say $B$ is the event of getting $6$ heads in a row and $A$ is the event of choosing two-headed coin.

Then by Bayes' theorem, $P(A|B) = \cfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

$P(A|B)$ is the conditional probability that the chosen coin is two-headed *given* we have tossed $6$ heads in a row using that coin.

$P(A \cap B)$ is the probability of choosing two-headed coin *and* getting $6$ heads in a row, which is simply $P(A)$.

So, $P(A |B) = \cfrac{P(A)}{P(B)}$

You have already found both $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) for Bayes' theorem.

Comment: P(A) would be 1/25 and P(B) would be 3/200. So the answer would be 3/8?

Comment: $P(A)$ is correct but $P(B)$ is probability of $6$ heads in a row which is $11/200$